# How to correctly re-format a python dictionary that is in unicode format?

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, formatting

I have some input data which is a python dictionary formatted as unicode. Something like this:

```
Input = {u'city': u'London', u'offer_type': u'3'}
```

And I need to create a script able to reformat the values of the dictionary. So if a value is an integer, like in the case of "offer_type" it sets it as integer. It the value is an string, like "city", it sets it as string. This can easily be done using the`str()` and `int()` functions.

But the problem is that my input data can vary, so the keys can be different, and also the associated values to those keys. So I need to somehow automatically distinguish when the unicode value is a number or a string, and reformat it.

My first idea was to take each value, try to convert them to integer, and if I retrieve an error message, then try to convert it to an string. But this is not pythonic at all, and I have doubts about the performance.

Thank you,
Álvaro

Comment: Why "convert to a string" ? I can understand the need for integer conversion, but for "internal use" unicode is the way to go (cf the unicode sandwich pattern: decode all byte strings to unicode at program's inputs, encode them to desired encoding at program's outputs, and only ever use unicode within your program).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

`Output = {}
 for key in Input.keys():
    Output[str(key)] = int(Input[key]) if Input[key].isdigit() else str(Input[key])
print Output`